# Start spring integration channel adapter and wait for the flow to complete

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have a spring boot application and have a requirement where I need to poll the database for some data and after receiving that data from db, poll another system for more data. I'm using spring integration and have defined the following components -

Channels:

1. evenChannel
2. controlChannel
3. systemChannel
4. taskStatusChannel (QueueChannel)
5. discardChannel

Adapters and ServiceActivators:

```
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "eventChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "1000", taskExecutor = "executor"),
            autoStartup = "false")
    @EndpointId("jdbcPollingAdapter")
    public JdbcPollingChannelAdapter pollingChannelAdapter() {
        JdbcPollingChannelAdapter adapter = new JdbcPollingChannelAdapter(this.dataSource, SQL);
        adapter.setRowMapper((rs, index) -> new TestEvent(rs.getString("eventName"), rs.getString("eventStatus"),
                rs.getTimestamp("createdDate"), rs.getTimestamp("updatedDate")));

        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "graphQLChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedRate = "1000"), autoStartup = "false")
    @EndpointId("graphQLPollingAdapter")
    public GraphQLPollingService graphQLPollingService() {
        return new GraphQLPollingService();
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "controlChannel")
    public ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean controlBus() {
        return new ExpressionControlBusFactoryBean();
    }
```

Integration Flows:

```
    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow1() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(eventChannel)
                              .filter(eventFilter)
                              .handle(msg -> {
                                  trigger("@jdbcPollingAdapter.stop()");
                                  trigger("@graphQLPollingAdapter.start()");
                              })
                              .get();

    }

    private void trigger(String expression) {
        controlChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>(expression));
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow discardFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(discardChannel)
                              .handle(msg -> log.info("Discarded msg: {}", msg))
                              .get();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow graphQLFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlow.from(graphQLChannel)
                              .filter(graphQLFilter)
                              .handle(msg -> {
                                  trigger("@graphQLPollingAdapter.stop()");
                                  taskStatusChannel.send(new GenericMessage<>("COMPLETED"));
                              })
                              .get();
    }
```

I start the JDBC polling adapter via a REST call but the call returns immediately. I want the call to wait for all the flows to complete and then return.

To summarize, I want something like this -

```
1. REST call to RestController 
2. RestController (start jdbc polling adapter and wait) 
3. when data received [1. stop jdbc polling adapter 2. start systemA polling adapter] 
4. when systemA data received [1. stop systemA polling adapter] 
5. RestController returns 200 OK
```

How can this be achieved?
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah... This is not the way how Inbound Channel Adapters are supposed to be used. It sounds more like you trigger some action via REST API and then you need to do some processing and return reply. So, you need to start from an `Http.inboundGateway()`, then `handle()` for `JdbcOutboundGateway`, then `handle()` for `GraphQl.gateway()` and that's it: you return its result back to the HTTP request. The HTTP can be replaced with a `WebFlux` for better processing of the reactive reply from a `GraphQl.gateway()`.

Calling `stop()/start()` for flow control is not correct from business logic.

Comment: Thanks Artem! I need to poll the database until I find the record that I'm looking for. Is there a way to use the `JdbcPollingChannelAdapter` to achieve this?

Comment: No. That is fully not correct to trigger inbound channel adapters like that. They have to be used as a beginning of the flow. You still can use that `JdbcOutboundGateway` with a `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` until you find a required record.